# Error: "Variable "entry" does not exist" on basic template

Tags: templating, craft3

I'm new to Craft and I'm stumbling at the first hurdle for Craft 3

I'm getting "Variable "entry" does not exist." and I'm certain it's something so simple I'm missing.

Case:

- Install craft 3 via composer
- Add a Single section called "Homepage" (URI: "/" | template: "index")
- Add "templates/index.twig" - test it with basic markup; displays correctly
- Add plain text field to homepage section ("homepageHeader")
- Fill out homepageHeader in control panel and save.
- Change template to literally only "{{entry.homepageHeader}}"
- Error above after page refresh

I must be missing something VERY simple. What is it?

Comment: In order to test if you are in the correct template, you can open the `homepage` entry directly in your cp list (with the world icon) do you receive `a route not found` or `template does not exists` exception when you do that? Note: in order to set an entry as homepage you should leave the uri blank => no `/`

Comment: Changing the URI to blank was the key! Feel free to add as an answer and I'll mark it. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to set an entry as your "homepage" entry you have to leave the `uri` in the section completely blank. It does not work when you insert a `/` because this route does not fetch the correct element thus Craft is not able to provide the `entry` variable in your twig template